# Pick the points on horizontal axis

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, array-merge

There are many sets of points on the horizontal axis of coordinate plane. If a point is plotted in between any set that set is reduced to that point. Given X Sets, find minimum number of points one should pick to reduce all points to minimum number of points.

**Input specification :**

input 1 ; X number of Sets 
input 2 : array consisting of X pairs,each pair indicating start and end of set

**Output specification:**
return integer as per question.

**Example 1 :**

input 1 : 3 
input 2 : [{1 ,3}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}]

Output : 1

[image]

**Example 2 :**

input 1 : 3 
input 2 : [{1 ,3}, {2, 5}, {6, 9}]

Output : 2

Can any one please help me with this ds algo question, I've faced this in an interview and trying to understand the problem but couldn't get it.

Comment: I think the solution is to represent each set as two events: a start event and an end event. Put all the events into an array and sort the array. (When a start event and an end event have the same number, the start event is ordered before the end event.) A single pass through the sorted array will produce the final answer.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm confused like set {1, 3} & {2,5} can be reduced to point 2 as well , I was bit confused on the question and the way of interpreting the output

Comment: What exactly is confusing?

Comment: The output is just the number of points you need to pick. It doesn't matter which points you pick, just how many are needed. So with `{1,3} & {2,5}`, you can pick either point 2 or point 3 to reduce the sets to a single point. But either way, the answer is 1.

Comment: @user3386109 butin example 2 , the output is 2 , that is confusing, can you please help explain

Comment: In example two, you need one point to reduce `{1,3} & {2,5}`. And then you need a second point to reduce `{6,9}`. So the answer is 2.

Comment: @user3386109 but {6, 9 } cannot be reduced since there is no point plotted between them to get it reduced as per question , is my understanding correct ?

Comment: If you choose point 7, then {6,9} is reduced from four points (6,7,8,9) to one point (7). You need to reduce all of the sets to the minimum number of points. I don't know if a set with only one point like `{3,3}` needs to be reduced. That's the kind of question the you have to ask during the interview.

Comment: @user3386109 ok got it, thank you!, on the solution part you were saying to put all events into an array means, all start & end event will be part of single array like [ 1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 9] & when sorted it would be like [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9] ??

Comment: You need to keep track of whether it's a start event, or an end event. So the sorted array (in python) is `[(1,'s'), (2,'s'), (3,'e'), (5,'e'), (6,'s'), (9,'e')]`. The rest is up to you, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Minimum points to be selected.**

```
static int minNumPoints(int[][] arr, int n)
{
    int steps = 1;
    int points = arr[0][1];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       if(arr[i][0] > points) {
           steps++;
           points = arr[i][1];
       }
    }
    return steps;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = { {1 ,3}, {2, 5}, {6, 9} };
    int n = arr.length;
    System.out.print(minNumPoints(arr, n));
}
```

**Output: 2**